# How to use custom pillar with salt orchestrate?

Tags: salt-stack

is it available to set custom pillar for salt orchestrate.

In the manual I found this:

```
    salt '*' state.highstate pillar='{"update_archive_name":     "new_archive_name.zip"}'
```

This example works fine.

But I need to set custom pillar for orchestrate procedure. I try like this:

```
salt-run state.orchestrate orchestration.install_update pillar='{"update_archive_name": "new_archive_name.zip"}'
```

And this variant doesn't work.

How to correct run orchestration in salt with custom pillar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation your example should work:

https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/runners/all/salt.runners.state.html#salt.runners.state.orchestrate